# Computing the average number of times that n non-overlapping heads occur

Tags: probability, markov-chains, monte-carlo

Considering a sequence of $100$ coin flips, how can I compute $z(n)$, the average number of times that $n$ non-overlapping heads occur?  (For example, six consecutive heads count as exactly two occurrences of three consecutive heads.)

If I understand well:

For example: "THHHTTTHHHHTHTH..."

Breaking down this example, we have $2$ occurrences of $3$ consecutive heads: "HHH", "HHH".

The probability of getting $6$ consecutive heads is $(1/2)^6 = 1/64$. But if this counts as $2$ occurrences of $3$ consecutive heads, then the probability to $z(3)$ is $2 * (1/64) = 1/32$.

Comment: @user2661923 That $\frac{100-2}{8}=12.25$ calculation allows overlaps.  A better attempt ignoring overlaps would be $\frac{100-2}{14}=7$ where $14$ is the expected number of tosses to get HHH, but this is only an approximation as it takes time to approach a smooth case, and the actual expected number is closer to $7.0408$

Comment: @Henry Nice comment.  I overlooked the entire issue of overlaps.  I therefore deleted my previous comment.

Comment: @Henry Answer given with what should be an exact computation (assuming that I made no *further* analytical errors).

Comment: @user2661923 an even better approximation is $\frac{100-2}{14}+\frac{2}{49}$ and I think the exact result may be $\frac{100-2}{14}+\frac{2}{49} +\frac{3}{49 \times 2^{100}}$ or more generally $\frac{n-2}{14}+\frac{2}{49} +\frac{3}{49 \times 2^{n}}$ when $n \equiv 1 \pmod 3$

Comment: @Henry I am unsure whether I am interpreting your last comment correctly.  I intended that my answer give an exact computation.  Do you disagree that my computation is exact.  If so, this would seem to imply that I have made an analytical error.  Did I?

Comment: @user2661923 I was not commenting on your answer, but I think mjqxxxx's answer  is indeed $7+\frac{2}{49} +\frac{3}{49 \times 2^{100}}$ and says it is the same as yours

Answer (score 2):

My initial analysis, which I left as a comment, computed the expectation as $~\displaystyle \frac{98}{8}.~$

I was basing this on [Linearity of Expectation](https://brilliant.org/wiki/linearity-of-expectation/),
which includes a proof that the formula applies even when the events are not independent of each other.

My idea was that from $~100~$ coin flips, there are $~98~$ opportunities for 3 consecutive heads, and each opportunity has a $~1/8~$ probability of occurring.

However, as indicated by Henry's comment, following the posting, I overlooked that the OP (i.e. original poster) was not enumerating *overlaps* as I was.  That is, both 4 consecutive heads and 5 consecutive heads are to be counted **once** only, while 6 consecutive heads is to count as 2 occurrences of 3 consecutive heads.

So, I deleted my original comment.

---

However, I just thought of a way of salvaging my original approach.  The computation of $~98/8~$ is accurate, except that (**for example**) it fails to adjust for the possibility of either 4 or 5 consecutive heads.

There are $~97~$ opportunities for $~4~$ consecutive heads, each of which has a probability of $~1/16~$ of occurring.

So, the **first revision** of my original computation is

$$\frac{98}{8} - \frac{97}{16}. \tag1 $$

Superficially, it would (**wrongly**) appear that the only thing wrong with the computation in (1) above is that it deducts each occurrence of 5 consecutive heads twice, rather than once.

So, a reasonable second revision is

$$\frac{98}{8} - \frac{97}{16} + \frac{96}{32} = \frac{294}{32} = \frac{147}{16} = 9.1875. \tag2 $$

---

The inaccuracy inherent in the computation in (2) above reflects that I am mis-managing exactly 7 consecutive heads, mis-managing exactly 8 consecutive heads, and so on.  So, my overall approach must be altered.

For $~n \in \{3,4,5,\cdots,100\},~$ and for $~k \in \{1,2,\cdots, 101 - n\},~$ let $~f(n,k)~$ denote the probability of **exactly** $~n~$ consecutive heads occurring, with the first Head occurring at coin toss $~k.~$

This means that $~f(3,1) = 1/16,~$ since the first $~4~$ coin tosses must be HHHT.  Similarly, $~f(3,2) = 1/32,~$ since the first $~5~$ coin tosses must be THHHT.

Each occurrence of exactly $~3,~4,~$ or $~5~$ consecutive heads is to be enumerated once. Each occurrence of exactly $~6,~7,~$ or $~8~$ consecutive heads is to be enumerated twice, and so forth.

So, using *Linearity of Expectation*, the overall expectation is

$$1 \times \left\{ ~\sum_{n=3}^5 \left[\sum_{k=1}^{101 - n} f(n,k)\right] ~\right\} \\
+ 2 \times \left\{ ~\sum_{n=6}^8 \left[\sum_{k=1}^{101 - n} f(n,k)\right] ~\right\} \\
+ 3 \times \left\{ ~\sum_{n=9}^{11} \left[\sum_{k=1}^{101 - n} f(n,k)\right] ~\right\} \\
+ \cdots. \tag3 $$

The overall expression in (3) above can be attacked by finding a pattern in the computations, and then generalizing to a final formula.

---

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{101 - n} f(n,k) ~: ~n = 3}$

$~\displaystyle f(3,1) = \frac{1}{16}.$

For $~\displaystyle 2 \leq k \leq 97, ~f(3,k) = \frac{1}{32}.~$

$~\displaystyle f(3,98) = \frac{1}{16} ~$ (i.e. last 4 tosses must be THHH).

Therefore,

$$\sum_{k=1}^{101 - 3} f(3,k) = \frac{96}{32} + \left[2 \times \frac{1}{16} \right] = \frac{96 + 4}{32} = \frac{100}{32}.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{101 - n} f(n,k) ~: ~n = 4}$

$~\displaystyle f(4,1) = \frac{1}{32}.$

For $~\displaystyle 2 \leq k \leq 96, ~f(4,k) = \frac{1}{64}.~$

$~\displaystyle f(4,97) = \frac{1}{32} ~$ (i.e. last 5 tosses must be THHHH).

Therefore,

$$\sum_{k=1}^{101 - 4} f(4,k) = \frac{95}{64} + \left[2 \times \frac{1}{32} \right] = \frac{95 + 4}{64} = \frac{99}{64}.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{101 - n} f(n,k) ~: ~4 < n \leq 98}$

$~\displaystyle f(n,1) = \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}.$

For $~\displaystyle 2 \leq k \leq (100 - n), ~f(n,k) = \frac{1}{2^{n+2}}.~$

$~\displaystyle f(n,101 - n) = \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}.$

Therefore,

$$\sum_{k=1}^{101 - n} f(n,k) = \frac{99 - n}{2^{n+2}} + \left[2 \times \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \right] = \frac{103 - n}{2^{n+2}}.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Final Computation}}$

(3) above may now be generalized to

$$1 \times \left[ ~\frac{100}{2^5} + \frac{99}{2^6} + \frac{98}{2^7} ~\right] \\
+ 2 \times \left[ ~\frac{97}{2^8} + \frac{96}{2^9} + \frac{95}{2^{10}} ~\right] \\
+ 3 \times \left[ ~\frac{94}{2^{11}} + \frac{93}{2^{12}} + \frac{92}{2^{13}} ~\right] \\
+ \cdots \\
+ 32 \times \left[ ~\frac{7}{2^{98}} + \frac{6}{2^{99}} + \frac{5}{2^{100}} ~\right] \\
+ 33 \times \left[ ~\frac{2}{2^{100}} + \frac{1}{2^{100}} ~\right].$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $z_n(m)$ be the expected number of non-overlapping runs of $n$ heads in the next $m$ coin flips.  More generally, let $y_n(k, m)$ be the expected number of non-overlapping runs of $n$ heads in the next $m$ coin flips given that we need $0<k\le n$ heads to complete the current run.  Then

- $z_n(m)=0$ for $m < n$;
- $z_n(m)=y_n(n, m)$;
- for $k > 1$,
  $y_n(k, m)=\frac{1}{2}y_n(k-1, m-1) + \frac{1}{2}z_n(m-1)$; and
- $y_n(1, m)=\frac{1}{2} + z_n(m-1)$.

These can be put together into a simple script:

```
   def z(n, m):
     if m < n: return 0
     return y(n, n, m)
   
   def y(n, k, m, cache={}):
     kk = (n, k, m)
     if kk in cache: return cache[kk]
     if k == 1:
       ret = Rational(1, 2) + z(n, m-1)
     else:
       ret = Rational(1, 2) * (y(n, k-1, m-1) + z(n, m-1))
     cache[kk] = ret
     return ret
```

When I evaluate $z_3(100)$, I get
$$
\frac{8925295042423247826864542976627}{1267650600228229401496703205376} \approx 7.04082 .
$$
This is between the lower bound of $33/8=4.125$ (considering $33$ non-overlapping runs of $3$, each with a probability $1/8$ of being "HHH") and the upper bound of $98/8=12.25$ (considering all possible runs of $3$, but allowing overlaps), as it should be.

---

*Update:*

It's actually a bit simpler to express the recursion in terms of $z_n(m)$ alone.  For instance, for $n=3$, we have

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
z_3(m) &=& y_3(3,m) \\
&=& \frac{1}{2}z_3(m-1) + \frac{1}{2}y_3(2,m-1) \\
&=& \frac{1}{2}z_3(m-1) + \frac{1}{4}z_3(m-2) + \frac{1}{4}y_3(1,m-2) \\
&=& \frac{1}{2}z_3(m-1) + \frac{1}{4}z_3(m-2) + \frac{1}{4}z_3(m-3) + \frac{1}{8}.
\end{eqnarray}
$$
More generally,
$$
z_n(m) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{z_n(m-k)}{2^k} + \frac{z_n(m-n) + 1}{2^{n}}.
$$
It seems like this should admit a generating-function solution.

Comment: Note that this result agrees exactly with @user2661923's final computation.

Comment: You probably intended to say $z_4(100) \approx 733/225$.  More generally $z_4(n) \approx \frac{n-3}{30} + \frac{11}{450}$.  The difference is $O(2^{-n})$ and when $n \equiv 0 \pmod 4$ is $\frac{17}{225 \times 2^n}$

Comment: Interestingly, for some reason the result $z_4(100)$ is extremely close to, but not equal to, $733/225$.  It differs by less than $10^{-31}$.  (Comment edited to fix typo.)